# Create Marker with lat and long from JSON file inside Assets folder

Tags: android

I created an android application and want to add Markers to my map with lat and long from JSON file inside Assets folder. I dont know what is the error in my code, my markers dont show up.

this is my Json file:

```
{
 "data" : [
{
"title": "Loja Coqueiros",
"lat": -8.8123083,
"lng": 13.2249500
},

 {
"title": "Loja Amilca Cabral",
"lat": -8.8265861,
"lng": 13.2274667
},

 {
"title": "Loja samba",
"lat":-8.8328611,
"lng": 13.2182861
}
]


 }
```

this is how i fetch the JSON file:

```
public String getJSONFromAssets() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputData = getAssets().open("locations.json");
            int size = inputData.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputData.read(buffer);
            inputData.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
```

I have added to my Array:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getJSONFromAssets());
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    if (arr != null)  
       for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
           locations.add(arr.get(i).toString());
```

And i create my marker :

```
for (int i=0;i< locations.size();i++) {

            try {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(obj.getJSONArray("lat").getDouble(0),
                                             obj.getJSONArray("lng").getDouble(0)))

                        .title((obj.getString("title")))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

Comment: They don't show, or they don't show where do you expect? Is there any error in the Logcat (JSONException, IOException)? Try to set the map position to the Marker position in order to verify it is not showing in a wrong place

Comment: Logcat dont show any error or Exeption. and the markers just dont show

Comment: Are you sure the marker position points the right place? Could you send me the coordinates of the first marker? Or paste your JSON file content?

Comment: my JSON file I already posted

Comment: lat : - 8.8123083
long : 13.2249500

Comment: Yes sorry I missed it, let me check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `obj.getJSONArray("lat").getDouble(0)`, you are accessing it in a wrong way. Get it from `locations` and parse it to double or if you want to get it from your json you must use `arr`:

```
arr.getJSONObject(0).getDouble("lat");
```

If you just want to get it right from the full JSON you must do:

```
obj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("lat");
```

Comment: I suppose you know there is other error. If you do it as in the provided code you are going to draw the first Marker three times, you must change `0` for `i` to draw all markers. And you should fix so many things like iterating through an object and using other, this can lead to errors

Comment: To show all markers you must replace the `0` for an `i`, as said before

Comment: i am new in android. i did not know about other error. is there any way you 
could help

Comment: What is the problem now? It should show all the markers, the last answer you provided is right.

Answer (score 2):

As User dolphinziyo said The problem is in obj.getJSONArray("lat").getDouble(0), you are accessing it in a wrong way.
Please replace your for loop with below for loop  :

```
for (int i=0;i< locations.size();i++) {
         JSONObject locationObj = new JSONObject(locations.get(i));
        try {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(locationObj.getDouble("lat"),
                            locationObj.getDouble("lan"))
                    .title((locationObj.getString("title")))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```